# why we need to use sort transformation before merge join transformation in ssis

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Can any one please tell me why we are sorting all the records before using merge component or merge join component? What is the Exact reason behind it?

Comment: This may not be exact, but i think it has to do more in the duplicate finding process where it expects a sorted input

Comment: You might want to take a look at this article on merge joins for a start: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sort-merge_join

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A merge requires sorted inputs because of how it works internally - a single pass through both inputs at the same time is sufficient to produce a merged sorted output. See the MSDN documentation for the SSIS [Merge Transformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141703.aspx) and [Merge Join Transformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141775.aspx) for a little more info.

If you don't want or need sorted output you could look at the [Union All Transformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141020.aspx) that just combines it's inputs into one output without any sorting.

Regards,

Rhys